# forms on lightboxes

Tags: php, css, forms, modal-dialog

I have made a simple home-made lightbox.  The lightbox contains forms which allows the user to submit data.  I placed a SIMPLE form on my SIMPLE lightbox, and I noticed that when I submit the form the lightbox closes automatically.  Why is it doing this, and how can I keep this from happening?  I'd like to submit a form on the lightbox and keep the lightbox unaffected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not possible if you submit the form using php it will submit to another page so it will refresh if you want to stay on the page you will have to look into using AJAX to submit the form and get the server response

There are some good technology's out there to do this like jquery AJAX

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/